# Adding tSetDynamicSchema component in Talend

Tags: talend, data-integration, talend-mdm

I am started working on positional parser  talend 6.4.1. As i am gone read data from dynamic schema so i need  tSetDynamicSchema component to proceed further. But i cant see tSetDynamicSchema  component in the Tool. Can anyone help me to add this component to tool?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `tSetDynamicSchema` is only available in Talend subscription (entreprise) version.  in Talend Open Studio, you need to define your schema at design time.